# Nrwl nx command to generate lib for nest module

Tags: nestjs, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I am new to nrwl nx cli and extensively searched through their documentation and could not find the command to generate the nestjs module as lib rather than the actual module within app.

The reason why I want to create the nestjs module as lib is becuase I have got several nestjs applications in my mono repo and as per nrwl nx guidelines if I have to share code, which is module in my case, it has to be a lib.

Can anyone please share the command to do the following thing:-

1. Generate nestsjs module in libs
2. Create nestjs service for that module in libs folder

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I got the command that does the job finally and sharing with other encase they require help

```
ng generate @nestjs/schematics:library mynestlib
```

Comment: with recent version of nx, you can use "ng g lib my-nest-lib", you'll be prompted for parent folder, and angular or typescript lib for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thierry Falvo but if I use that command it wil never ask for nestjs and won't scaffold the nestjs module and app

Comment: I would not recommend using `@nestjs/schematics:library` directly as it does not update `nx.json`, `angular.json`, etc. properly. You'd have to do it manually each time. Please upvote this feature, if still interested: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1010

Comment: It's possible now to create a NestJS library including controller and service inside a Nx library: `ng g @nrwl/nest:library my-lib  --controller --service`. See https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/docs/angular/api-nest/schematics/library.md

Comment: You can also install the nest plugin for nx
https://nx.dev/angular/plugins/nest/overview

Answer (score 1):

Quote from Nx Workspace [official documentation](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/plugins/angular/generators/library) :

> Creating a Lib Adding new libs to an Nx Workspace is done by using the
> Angular CLI generate command, just like adding a new app.
>
> ```
> ng generate lib mylib
> ng generate library mylib # same thing
> ```
>
> This will create a new lib, will place it in the libs directory, and
> will configure the `angular.json` and `nx.json` files to support the
> new lib.
>
> Run `ng generate lib --help` to see the list of available options.

> `ng generate lib mylib --directory=myteam` will create a new application in `libs/myteam/mylib`.

If `--directory` is not defined, it will ask you in which directory it should be generated, and what framework should be used (Angular or TS).

If it's not working, please, maybe you should check your Nx version, and also your `angular.json`.

`@nrwl/schematics` could not be the default collection used as [this issue
mentioned](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/524).

**angular.json**

```
"cli": {
  "defaultCollection": "@nrwl/schematics",
  "packageManager": "yarn"
},
```

Comment: I understand what you saying and checked what you have told but what I am saying is when you create library using the ng g lib command, it only give options of Angular, React and Typescript framework only but nothing for NestJS

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you was looking for. But maybe you should not use "generate lib" from NestJS because it won't add needed Nx config in angular.json, and all tsconfig files. So after generating a TS lib with Nx, you can generate module and service with NestJS. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice mate, that is what I am doing now. it is bit of pain but I guess that is the only option as using command mentioned above does not update the nx.json and angular.json file as you have said

Answer (score 1):

I've came across the same problematic lately.

While @Atul Chaudhary can solve the issue in a different way,
I could solve my problem following [this comment](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1658#issuecomment-516870591)

So basically, you just have to add a new `nest-cli.json` file to your *nx workspace root folder* and specify these basic informations according to your project's structure.

#### `nest-cli.json` basic example

```json
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/api/src"
}
```

Hope it can help some people :)

Answer (score 0):

Nx now has direct support for NestJS via their [`@nrwl/nest` plugin](https://nx.dev/packages/nest). They also have [this tutorial](https://nx.dev/angular-tutorial/05-add-node-app#create-a-nestjs-application) that you may find useful.